# Need to generate the Regex between Two delimiters

Tags: regex, unix, ansible

I need to find a regex which can give me String between two delimiters(In this case @)

I have previously used this (?<=@)(.*?)(?=@)

But the problem with this is

Instead of picking two tokens I am getting three token from this line

```
UPDATE XYZ
SET EVENTTIME='21:01', DEADLINE='21:21',
COMPONENTNAME = '@token1@_some_update',checkthgis= '@token2@' WHERE TYPE='STATIC_UPDATE'
```

1. token1
2. _some_update',checkthgis=
3. token 2

I am using this Ansible code for this

```
   - name: Find the tokens (@----@) in the fileString
      set_fact:
        tokens: "{{ fileString | regex_findall(regexp)}}"
      vars:
        regexp: '(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\@)'


    - name: Replace the token in the configuration files
      replace:
        path: "{{file}}"
        regexp: "@{{token}}@"
        replace: "{{ lookup('ini', '{{token}} type=properties file=/root/xyz/myfile.properties default=@{{token}}@')}}"
      with_items: "{{tokens}}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: token
```

Ideally this should give me only

token1 and token2

Answer (score 0):

If you use `(?<=@).*?(?=@)` the pattern will match any 0+ chars as few as possible between each pair of `@` in the string, and once matched, it goes on to look for matches at the place were it found the previous match and to the right of it. Since the `(?=@)` is a lookahead, a zero width assertion, the regex may start matching on the `@` that has just been the ending delimiter.

You may use

```
(?<=@)([^\s@]+)(?=@)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJXCdf/1)

It matches:

- `(?<=@)` - a position immediately preceded with `@`
- `([^\s@]+)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars other than whitespace and `@`
- `(?=@)` - a  position immediately followed with `@`